# Javascript pass variable to function name

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I’m trying to create a simple loop of animation functions. I've stored their names in an array and am able to log out each object as a string with a click event. However I can't seem to call the corresponding functions of that event

I've tried to do this but I get an error nt[rt] is not a function

```
arrAnimations[activeScene]()
```

I've tried many approaches from stack overflow from similar questions, such as creating a helper function like this

```
myFunction = function(){};   
var arrAnimations = {italy: myFunction};

arrAnimations['activeScene']();//executes the function
```

and this

```
var tmp = arrAnimations[activeScene]
window[tmp]
```

Here is the code:

```js
var arrAnimations = [
  'italy',
  'czech',
  'russia'
]

var activeScene = 0;

document.getElementById('animate').addEventListener("click",
  function incNumber() {
      if (activeScene < arrAnimations.length - 1) {
          activeScene++;
      } else if (activeScene = arrAnimations.length - 1) {
          activeScene = 0;
      }
      // console.log(arrAnimations[activeScene])
  }
)

function italy() { console.log('italy') }

function czech() { console.log('czech') }

function russia() { console.log('russia') }
```

```html
<div id="animate">Animate</div>
```

Comment: It looks like it should be `window[arrAnimations[activeScene]]`

Comment: Why don't you create an array of anonymous functions instead of array of function names?

Comment: "can't get any to do what I want" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Yes, you would need a helper object that stores the functions, next to the array with their names. (Or follow @Mohammad's suggestion)

Comment: Btw, the `activeScene = arrAnimations.length - 1` assignment should be a `activeScene == arrAnimations.length - 1` condition. Or be omitted altogether (just `else { … }`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array can store the actual functions themselves, instead of the function names.

```js
function italy()  { console.log('italy') }
function czech()  { console.log('czech') }
function russia() { console.log('russia') }

var arrAnimations = [ italy, czech, russia ]
```

Then locate the item in the array, and call it:

```js
var activeScene = 0;
arrAnimations[activeScene]()
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
function italy()  { console.log('italy') }
function czech()  { console.log('czech') }
function russia() { console.log('russia') }

var arrAnimations = [ italy, czech, russia ]

var index = 0;

function callNextFunction() {
    index = index >= arrAnimations.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1
    
    arrAnimations[index]()
}

var btn = document.getElementById('animate')
btn.addEventListener("click", callNextFunction)
```

```html
<button id="animate">Animate</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your commented out line:

```
console.log(arrAnimations[activeScene])
```

You're trying to call a method on the array, which doesn't exist. It's an array of strings. Instead, you need to get the string value, then use that to call a method on the window.

```
window[arrAnimations[activeScene]]();
```

With that said though, I'd make your code a bit simpler and use lambda functions, and avoid a couple of if statements, try this:

```
<div id="animate">Animate</div>

<script>
    var arrAnimations = [
        () => console.log('italy'),
        () => console.log('czech'),
        () => console.log('russia')
    ]

    var activeScene = 0;

    document.getElementById('animate').addEventListener('click', () => {

        arrAnimations[activeScene]();

        activeScene++;
        activeScene = activeScene % arrAnimations.length;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
italy = () => console.log('italy')
czech = () => console.log('czech')
russia = () => console.log('russia')
```

if Array of functions:

```
let arrAnimationsAsFunctions = [ italy , czech , russia];
arrAnimationsAsFunctions.forEach(animation => animation())
```

if Array of Strings:

```
let arrAnimationsAsStrings = [ 'italy' , 'czech' , 'russia' ];
arrAnimationsAsStrings.forEach(animation => eval(animation)())
```

use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to run a string as JS code

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
foo = () => console.log('foo')
bar = () => console.log('bar')
baz = () => console.log('baz')

fns = {
  foo,
  bar,
  baz
}

Object.keys(fns).forEach(fn => fns[fn]())

fns['foo']()
fns['bar']()
```

Note: you can't cast a string to a function like this, at least in Javascript:

```
let fn = () => {}
let foo = 'fn'
foo()  // X
// foo is a string, not a function, It is just a coincidence that the content of the string is same with the function's name
```